# Interaction with .bat file in VBA

Tags: vba, shell, batch-file, sendkeys

I am interacting with a .bat file launched in my VBA code. The shell is open and I managed to send a few commands however some other commands fail like F9, DOWN and UP.

Here is my chunk of code :

```
Sub OpenBrice()
Path = "F:\Brice\valpp"
ChDir Path
Shell Path & "\Brice.bat", vbNormalFocus

'Wait during opening BRICE
Wait (2) 

'PASS
SendKeys "123"
Wait (1) 
'Press Enter:
SendKeys "~"
Wait (1)

'Update current date
SendKeys "O"
Wait (1)
SendKeys "F"
Wait (1)
SendKeys (Format(Now(), "ddmmyy"))
Wait (1)
SendKeys "{ESC}"
Wait (2)
SendKeys "{F9}"
```

The problem happens on the last line, {F9} doesn't work, as well for {DOWN} or {UP}..
Further in the code, the line : `SendKeys "{F8}"` works perfectly...

I suspect a bad configuration of the shell or something similar ? Thanks a lot!

P.S : I am just testing some code, I know that I should declare all my variable and use Option Explicit

Comment: Are you sure that F9 is the problem? It might be caused by the ESC in the step before.

Comment: The {ESC} worked well in the program since it changes the view in the menu displayed. To be sure, I checked F9 before the ESC and it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any other program catching it? Some laptops have crazy keyboard mappings

Comment: What do you mean by catching it ?